# Javascript getParams breaking JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a URL with JSON in it.

This is the URL:

```
http://localhost:1234/asset/view-details.action?id=5&assetJson=%%7B%0A%20%20%22assetDesc%22%3A%20%22AMERICAN%20HARDWARE%20%26%20TOOLS%22%0A%7D
```

The JSON file can be retrieved with:

```
const assetJson = getParams.get('assetJson');
const assetDetail = JSON.parse(assetJson);
```

assetDetail should be equal to:

```
{
  "assetDesc": "AMERICAN HARDWARE & TOOLS"
}
```

In JavaScript, every time I try getParams.get('assetJson'), I get this error "Unexpected end of JSON input".  It's because the returned value is cut off at the ampersand( & ).  I end up with:

```
{
  "assetDesc": "AMERICAN HARDWARE
```

& TOOLS" }  is completely cut off.

Is there a way to fix this?  I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Something is not properly URL-encoding the JSON string.

Comment: If its a JSON object, why not use something like: `console.log(assetJson.assetDesc);`?

Comment: Whoever puts this JSON in the URL should properly stringily and URL-encode it

Comment: There's really not enough to go on here to provide more specific help.

Comment: this is the root problem: `I have a URL with JSON in it using assetJson=.` you should not use JSON in URLs.

Comment: Unfortunately the decision to add JSON to the URL was made before I joined the team.  So I don't have a choice in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `URLSearchParams` and it's `get` function along with `JSON.parse`.

The `substring(1)` that I'm using exists to get rid of a % sign that is coming up before the JSON start `{`.

```js
var str = "http://localhost:1234/asset/view-details.action?id=5&assetJson=%%7B%0A%20%20%22assetDesc%22%3A%20%22AMERICAN%20HARDWARE%20%26%20TOOLS%22%0A%7D";

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(str);
myParam = urlParams.get('assetJson').substring(1);
myParam = JSON.parse(myParam)

console.log(myParam.assetDesc)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
const parseResult = new DOMParser().parseFromString(window.location.search, 'text/html');
  // replace "&" with it's URL encoding
  const parsed = parseResult.documentElement.textContent.replace('%20&', '%20%26');

  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(parsed);
  const assetJson = urlParams.get('assetJson');
  const assetDetail = JSON.parse(assetJson);
```

Comment: it can be solved by simply adding `.substring(1);` to the `get` and not using all of that other stuff. The problem is there is a random % added to the beginning of the json.